# Secure my backend API hoisted in cloudrun and appengine

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, api-gateway, google-cloud-load-balancer

I have an Android/iOS app. I have multiple backend services in GCP Cloud Run and Appengine which have multiple get and post requests.
I have set up a global https load balancer to balance the traffic. In my Load balancer I have selected Backend type: Serverless network endpoint group (App Engine, Cloud Run, Cloud Functions)
I want to use some kind of authentication for my services like security token or something else like API gateway to secure my backend form unauthorised access.
Can anyone suggest ?